# Change Currency code and amount according to user's country in stripe checkout page

Tags: javascript, node.js, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

```
const session = stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [{
      name: 'T-shirt',
      description: 'Comfortable cotton t-shirt',
      images: ['https://example.com/t-shirt.png'],
      amount: 100,
      currency: 'usd',
      quantity: 1,
    }], 
    success_url: 'https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
  });
```

I created a **Checkout Session** but **amount** and **currency** is hard coded right now .When user click on a button.then **amount** and **currency** should change according to the user's **country detail**.

**For Example** -

price of a product is **$10**.

if somebody buys this product in **USA**. he should see **$10** and **USD** at **Stripe Checkout page**.

if somebody buys this product in **India**.he should see **₹700** ($1=₹70) and **INR** at **Stripe Checkout page**.

Comment: Did you find the solution facing the same issue in stripe ??

Answer (score 0):

Checkout won't automatically convert between currencies for you, you have to implement that yourself. For instance:

When your user selects their country and clicks "buy", you should POST the country code to your server. Then you create a new Checkout Session with the right currency and amount and return the Checkout session ID to your frontend, where you redirect to Checkout as per the docs: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time#redirect-checkout